# Create XML based on schema in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm looking for means to create XML documents based on schema in PHP.

Default PHP go-to solution is usually SimpleXMLElement but as the name implies, it is fine for creating simple XML documents but becomes a burden if you need to create more complex document.

Consider the following schema, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="test">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="step1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="step2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="step3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This requires that the elements "step1", "step2" and "step3" to be in certain order, if present in the document.

In order to use SimpleXMLElement to create document compliant with the above schema you need to know in which order "step1" and "step2" need to be in the document. Following, for example, will fail to create valid document:

```
$xml=new SimpleXMLElement('<test/>');
$xml->step2='This is step 2';
$xml->step1='This is step 1';
print $xml->asXML();
```

Output has "step1" and "step2" in wrong order.

Does PHP have built-in functionality to build XML documents that would be compliant with specific schema? For example in above code desired functionality would be to correctly sequence the elements as required by the schema, not based on the order they were added.

At a quick glance neither DOMDocument nor XMLWriter support use of schema when generating the document, even if DOMDocument can validate against it.

---

*Edit to further emphasize the use-case:*

Consider the following extremely simplified XML, for example:

```
<test>
    <sender>
        <name>Sender 1</name>
        <addr>192.168.0.1</addr>
        <descr>This is the peer sending the information</descr>
    </sender>
    <receiver>
        <name>Gateway 1</name>
        <addr>10.2.1.2</addr>
        <descr>This is the intended recipient</descr>
    </receiver>
</test>
```

In the context of the question I'd like to decopule the code from the data so that it doesn't matter in which order the `//sender` and `//recipient` are added into the document.

The aim is to minimize the boilerplate code required to serialize the PHP object (or other structure) into XML document.

Currently one possibility is first to store the information into object and then serialize it into the XML document:

```
class XMLDoc1 {
    private $sender=[];
    private $receiver=[];

    public function setParty($name, $addr, $descr) {
        $res['name']=$name;
        $res['addr']=$addr;
        $res['descr']=$descr;
        return $res;
    }

    public function setSender($name, $addr, $descr) {
        $this->sender=$this->setParty($name,$addr,$descr);
    }

    public function setReceiver($name, $addr, $descr) {
        $this->receiver=$this->setParty($name,$addr,$descr);
    }

    public function setXmlParty(SimpleXMLElement $node, $party) {
        $node->name=$party['name'];
        $node->addr=$party['addr'];
        $node->descr=$party['descr'];
    }

    public function getxml() {
        $xml=new SimpleXMLElement('<test/>');
        $this->setXmlParty($xml->addChild('sender'),$this->sender);
        $this->setXmlParty($xml->addChild('receiver'),$this->receiver);
        return $xml->asXML();
    }
}

$x=new XMLDoc1();
$x->setSender('Origin', '192.168.0.2','Party sending the information');
$x->setReceiver('Target','10.2.1.3','Intended recipient of the information');
print $x->getxml();
```

Code above will guarantee that the XML elements are always generated in correct order.

That said, preference would be to be able to store the data directly into the XML document itself and amend it on the fly while keeping it valid all the time. Something along the lines of:

```
class XMLDoc2 {
    /** @var SimpleXMLElement */
    private $xml;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->xml=new SimpleXMLElement('<test/>');
    }

    public function setParty(SimpleXMLElement $node, $name, $addr, $descr) {
        $node->name=$name;
        $node->addr=$addr;
        $node->descr=$descr;
    }

    public function setSender($name, $addr, $descr) {
        $this->setParty($this->xml->addChild('sender'),$name,$addr,$descr);
    }

    public function setReceiver($name, $addr, $descr) {
        $this->setParty($this->xml->addChild('receiver'),$name,$addr,$descr);
    }

    public function getxml() {
        return $this->xml->asXML();
    }

}

$x=new XMLDoc2();
$x->setReceiver('Target','10.2.1.3','Intended recipient of the information');
$x->setSender('Origin', '192.168.0.2','Party sending the information');
print $x->getxml();
```

This code works if `setReceiver()` and `setSender()` are called in correct order.

With more complex document boilerplate code required to serialize the information into the XML becomes considerable and essentially duplicates what is already defined in the XSD.

Core of the question is whether PHP has means to cater for this out of the box or is additional framework is needed.

Comment: I'm not sure if any language has something like your after (could easily be wrong).  Think it does come down to either coding the writing of the data as it's needed directly or perhaps a builder pattern so that you collect all the data and then write it out - although again - having to write it yourself in the correct sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The following DTO class provides methods for data transfer and renders this data to the desired and valid output format (in this case it is XML).

Code:

```
class XMLDoc2
{
    private $senders = [];

    private $receivers = [];

    public function addSender($name, $addr, $descr)
    {
        $this->senders[] = ['name' => $name, 'addr' => $addr, 'descr' => $descr];
    }

    public function addReceiver($name, $addr, $descr)
    {
        $this->receivers[] = ['name' => $name, 'addr' => $addr, 'descr' => $descr];
    }

    public function getXml()
    {
        $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
        $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $xml->formatOutput = true;

        $root = $xml->createElement("test");

        foreach ($this->senders as $sender) {
            $senderNode = $this->createParty($xml, 'sender', $sender['name'], $sender['addr'], $sender['descr']);
            $root->appendChild($senderNode);
        }

        foreach ($this->receivers as $receiver) {
            $receiverNode = $this->createParty($xml, 'receiver', $receiver['name'], $receiver['addr'], $receiver['descr']);
            $root->appendChild($receiverNode);
        }

        $xml->appendChild($root);

        return $xml->saveXML();
    }

    private function createParty(DOMDocument $xml, $elementName, $name, $addr, $descr)
    {
        $node = $xml->createElement($elementName);

        $node->appendChild($xml->createElement("name", $name));
        $node->appendChild($xml->createElement("addr", $addr));
        $node->appendChild($xml->createElement("descr", $descr));

        return $node;
    }

}

$x = new XMLDoc2();
$x->addReceiver('Target', '10.2.1.3', 'Intended recipient of the information');
$x->addSender('Origin', '192.168.0.2', 'Party sending the information');
echo $x->getXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
  <sender>
    <name>Origin</name>
    <addr>192.168.0.2</addr>
    <descr>Party sending the information</descr>
  </sender>
  <receiver>
    <name>Target</name>
    <addr>10.2.1.3</addr>
    <descr>Intended recipient of the information</descr>
  </receiver>
</test>
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid serialization stage that requires me to effectively reproduce the schema in the code; having to do the "appendChild" in correct order. This is fine for simple XML documents, but becomes very tedious for more complex documents. The point is to decouple the code from data representation as much as possible.

Comment: Why do you need this additional level of abstraction? Are you trying to create an XML document based on a schema without finding its structure in the source code?

Comment: this is more about not wanting to duplicate structure of the XML in the source code. I edited the question to further explain this.

Comment: Aha ok, thanks to the new information I have adjusted my answer.